# One-versus-one or one-versus-all?

Tags: machine-learning, r-caret

I'm using the CARET package in R for multiclass classification. I have 3 classes and I use the method *train* for training purposes. Here is the code for it:

```
trained.model.rf <- train(x = dataset.train[,-c(ncol(dataset.train))], y = dataset.train[,ncol(dataset.train)],method='rf',
                        trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=10), allowParallel=TRUE, tuneLength = 6)
model.rf <- trained.model.rf$finalModel
result.rf <- predict(model.rf, dataset.test, type="response")
```

For the *dataset.train* I have the three classes together.
How can I tell if this is an one-versus-one or one-versus-all aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

After a second read i realized you might just be asking what Caret is doing and not which one you should pick. Sadly i can't answer that and i have to add that Caret's documentation is awful (they could learn something from scikit-learn)!

If there is no specific reason, i would not care that much in your case (small number of classes + random-forest; using SVMs or having many classes though it would be interesting to see what's used)

**/Edit**

There is not much difference in regards to performance with well-working underlying classifiers [reference](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/rifkin04a/rifkin04a.pdf).

One-vs-All is usually the default in most libraries i tried.

But there is a possible trade-off when thinking of the underlying classifiers and data-sets:

Let's call the number of classes **N**. The samples of your data-set is called **M**.

#### One vs. All

- Will train N classifiers on the whole data-set
- **Consequences:**

  - It's doing a linear-size of classification-learnings which scales well with the number of classes

    - That's probably the reason it's often default as it's also well-working with 100 classes or more
  - It's learning on the whole data-set, which can be a problem if the underlying classifier is complexity-wise bounded by sample-size

    - Popular example: **SVM**s are complexity-wise between `O(m^2)-O(m^3)` in  (depending on kernel & kernel-cache; ignoring SGD-based approaches)
    - SVMs can therefore be troublesome to learn on huge data-sets (compare with OvO below)

#### One vs. One

- Will train `N over 2` classifiers on some partial data-set
- **Consequences**:

  - It's doing an exponential-size of classification-learning (in regards to the number of classes) which scales very bad with the number of classes
  - If your data-set is balanced, it's working on `M/N*2` samples (only the samples of the two selected pairs are used)

    - This can help compared to OvA if the classifier-complexity is dominated by sample-size (like mentioned above)

In your case you got a small set of classes. If your library is supporting both approaches, i would use OvO first. But this is, like explained, dependent on your classifier and class-statistics.

While the paper referenced above says OvA should not be worse than OvO, i can imagine the latter can provide more safety if your setup is kind of imperfect (badly performing classifier, ...).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment! As you have stated, Caret documentation is awful, it barely says anything about OvA. I have asked other people and it seems my classification isn't doing neither OvA nor OvO since random forests can work with multiple classes, it'll just adjust its leaves. And if you look at it I'm using the train function with samples from the 3 classes. If I were using OvA or OvO I would have done some manipulation with data in order to perform different training modules. I guess we can never know what is happening inside caret. Anyway, thank you very much for the explanation!